# Distinct values from various fields in MongoDB collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am using [node-mongodb-native](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/) to fire mongodb queries using node js.
There is a collection name 'locations', which have following fields:

`sublocality1`, `sublocality2`, `sublocality3`, `city`.

I want to fetch overall distinct values from these fields.

Eg:
Documents:

```
{
  'sublocality1':'a',
  'sublocality2':'a',
  'sublocality3': 'b',
  'city': 'c'
}

{
  'sublocality1':'b',
  'sublocality2':'a',
  'sublocality3': 'b',
  'city': 'a'
}
```

The query should return

```
['a' , 'b', 'c']
```

I tried following:

```
Run distinct queries for each of the fields:
collection.distinct('sublocality1',..){},
collection.distinct('sublocality2',..){},
collection.distinct('sublocality3',..){},
collection.distinct('city',..){}
```

Insert the result from these queries into a list, and search for distinct items across list.

Can I optimize this? Is it possible running a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could aggregate it on the database server as below:

- `Group` Individual document, to get the values of each intended field
  in an array.
- `Project` a field named `values` as the `union` of all the intended field
  values, using the [$setUnion](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operator.
- `Unwind` values.
- `Group` all the records, to get the distinct values.

Code:

```
Collection.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":"$_id",
         "sublocality1":{$push:"$sublocality1"},
         "sublocality2":{$push:"$sublocality2"},
         "sublocality3":{$push:"$sublocality3"},
         "city":{$push:"$city"}}},
{$project:{"values":{$setUnion:["$sublocality1",
                                "$sublocality2",
                                "$sublocality3",
                                "$city"]}}},
{$unwind:"$values"},
{$group:{"_id":null,"distinct":{$addToSet:"$values"}}},
{$project:{"distinct":1,"_id":0}}
],function(err,resp){
   // handle response
})
```

Sample o/p:

```
{ "distinct" : [ "c", "a", "b" ] }
```

If you want the results to be sorted, you could apply a `sort` stage in the pipeline before the final `project` stage.

Comment: Thankyou BatScream. But for some reason, its returning, empty array: I tried `collection.aggregate([
                {$group:{"_id":"$_id",
                    "subLocality1":{$push:"$address_components.subLocality1"},
                    "subLocality2":{$push:"$address_components.subLocality2"},
                    "subLocality3":{$push:"$address_components.subLocality3"},
                    "city":{$push:"$address_components.city"}}},
                {$project:{"values":{$setUnion:["$address_components.subLocality1",
                    "$address_components.subLocality2",`

Comment: `"$address_components.subLocality3",
                    "$address_components.city"]}}},
                {$unwind:"$values"},
                {$group:{"_id":null,"distinct":{$addToSet:"$values"}}},
                {$project:{"distinct":1,"_id":0}}
            ],function(err,resp){`

Comment: For space constraint, I divided my code into two comment box. subLoclity1, subLocality2, etc. are nested document.
`"address_components" : {
    "city" : "Hyderabad",
    "subLocality1" : "Khairatabad",
    "subLocality2" : "",
    "subLocality3" : "",
}`;

Comment: @ritesh_NITW Your `$project` stage is wrong, it should be - `{$project:{"values":{$setUnion:["$subLocality1","$subLocality2",...]` and so on..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and solution. 
Quick question: Can we modify the query to add a condition: The result should be a substring of a search term q. ie. the distinct elements should should contain string q, as a sub-string.

Comment: @ritesh_NITW - At the beginning of the pipeline stage and after the unwind stage, - you need to add a `$match` stage with a `regex` query to filter the documents which start with `q` - `/^q/`. You could post a separate question on that if you are not successful, but it should be straight forward, really sorry, but a modification to the existing answer would deviate it away from the answer to the original question.

Comment: You can also use $addToSet instead of $push in that first stage, it will reduce the pipeline a bit.

Comment: @Zlatko - Actually, that would not make a difference here. Since, at that stage, all the fields would have only one value in them. That step is just to transform the field to an array of one element.